# Select limit on foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Products and products-sub. I want to show all the available colors for each product and a picture for that too.

So, my product table contains:

id,name,description

My product-sub table contains:

id, parentID, color, pic

I want to select all the colors and the pictures of one product and show it on the page. But I don’t want to show all the products on the same page.

```
select p.name, s.color, s.pic, p.id
from products-sub s
    inner join products as p on p.id = s.parentID
```

This is my current query, and I want 50 unique s.parentID's.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to limit unique foreign keys ... like i want all the colors of a products, but i want 50 unique products

Comment: You can join on a subquery with a limit: `JOIN (SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 50) p`

Comment: @shmosel you a life saver.

Comment: should i delete the question? or you post the answer and i will mark it

Comment: I would say give @shmosel an opportunity to re-post his info as an 'Answer'; there's no reason to ever delete it, as this could help others with the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to join on the parent table using a subquery with a `LIMIT`, e.g.

```
... JOIN (SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 50) p ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want 50 products, then use a subquery:

```
select p.name, s.color, s.pic, p.id 
from products_sub s inner join
     (select p.*
      from products p
      limit 50
     ) p
     on p.id = s.parentID;
```

This assumes, of course, that all the products have at least one sub.

Comment: You have the right answer too. but shmosel told me first. no hard feelings bro. Thank you btw